# Preg-match (allow 4-15 alpha-num-underscore chars)

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

Before you say I could find it online... I tried but I am not experienced with the subject :(

Anyway, here is the pattern I need for php preg_match:

- must contain minimum 4 and max 15 chars
- only alpha-numb chars allowed
- underscore allowed but not at beginning

Need it to control username entries.

Thank you!!!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$pattern = "/^[a-zA-Z0-9][_a-zA-Z0-9]{3,14}$/";

if(preg_match($pattern, $username)){
// The username matches the pattern – accept it
}
else{
// The username doesn’t match the pattern – reject it
}
```

This is how it works:

`^` Match the beginning of the string
`[a-zA-Z0-9]` An alphanumeric character
No quantifier given, so match exactly one character
`[_a-zA-Z0-9]` An underscore or an alphanumeric character
`{3,14}` Match a minimum of 3 and a maximum of 14 characters
`$` Match the end of the string

Comment: Thank you for prompt help on this. I like the way you explained it :) Will accept your question ...

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
$re = '/^(?!_)\w{4,15}$/';
```